# How to keep class with ProGuard

Tags: proguard

I'm using ProGuard and I want to keep a class with all its methods.

So what's the difference between

```
-keep class Foo
```

and

```
-keep class Foo {*;}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-keep class Foo` makes sure the class Foo (but not necessarily its contents) remains present with that name in the output.

`-keep class Foo { *; }` makes sure the class Foo *and all of it fields and methods* remain present with their original names in the output.

See the ProGuard manual > Usage > [Keep Options](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/usage.html#keepoptions).

Comment: Thanks, Eric. I saw the manual actually, but it doesn't mention the difference... I'm wondering what it means by keeping an empty class. Should it has at least a constructor, or really nothing?

Comment: That's a subtle detail indeed: `-keep class Foo` keeps the class, along with its parameterless constructor, if it exists. The idea is to ensure that `Class.forName(foo)` continues to work.